# python versions are not working in ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

In my ubuntu system, the terminal was not working properly actually I could not able to open it. So I search for solutions and people suggest to remove python 3.6 so I remove it and reinstall it after that I am facing many errors which are mentioned below then I tried to remove all python versions and virtualenv and reinstall all things but still it gives me same errors.

```
trt@trt-Vostro-15-3568:~$ python
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 183
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

trt@trt-Vostro-15-3568:~$ virtualenv venv 
Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 79, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 652, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 64
    async def _ag(): yield
                    ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function

trt@trt-Vostro-15-3568:~$ python
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 183
    file=sys.stderr)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

trt@trt-Vostro-15-3568:~$ python3.6
bash: /usr/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory
```

If anyone has any idea about this then, please help. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you remove python 3.6? How did you reinstall it?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version *exactly*?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have run these two commands for removing python3  $ sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

$ sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3

Comment: So you're now mimicking Python 3.6 with Python 3.5? Yes, that will not work. Why do you even think that that works? Just Python 3.5 instead then.

Comment: *Never*, ever just `sudo rm` some file if you don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an issue which I am facing. I have set PYTHONPATH which is pointing to python3.6 dir which is not required to set explicitly. So I removed it and then python 2.7 and 3.5 works fine. Only getting errors in python3.6.

Answer (score 2):

did you try only "python3" ?

And if it's doesn't work, try to remove and reinstall another version of python, like python-2.7 and try again.

Comment: Okay, I will try.